# Path of a block

Tags: blocks

We have a home page (Drupal 7) on which we have a block that we want to cache for only 1 minute while the rest of the page can be cached longer.  We are using Akamai and Varnish for this.

We implemented this block as a module and it properly implements the hook hook_block_view().  Once this module is deployed it shows up nicely in the Blocks area and then I can drop it in one of the regions on the home page.

So I was hoping that we could create a URL for this block that we can use to render its contents on the home page, and provide this URL to varnish and tell it to not to cache anything below this URL for more than a minute.